# EF5: how to select entity with it's child entities with raw SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-5

For the purpouse of the application that I developing I need to select entities which have navigation properties to another entities with native sql query.

This is my entity classes:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int? CodeId { get; set; }
    public CodeModel Code { get; set; }
}

public class CodeModel
{
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

My SQL query is:

```
 string sql = "SELECT u.* FROM UserModel AS u" +
              "INNER JOIN CodeModel AS c" +
              "ON c.UserId = u.UserId";
```

and the my C# method is:

```
public IEnumerable<UserModel> GetUsers()
{
    var users = dbContext.UserModel.SqlQuery(sql);

    return users;   
}
```

In result I get the users but the navigation property for Code on UserModel class is null. How to do this task with native query? I know how to do it with LINQ.

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try `*` instead of `u.*`? You may want to use `dbContext.UserModel.Include("Code")` too, not sure, didn't try it myself.

Comment: I am not sure what you are after, but isn't it just:

SELECT U.*, C.CodeId, C.Code, C.UserId - this will allow you to create CodeModel object.

Other comments:
First of all, you should use stored procedures instead of query stored in your application (advantages of SP over queries are widely described over the internet)
Second thing - list fields you are selecting instead using asterisk. Asterisk is nice for test/ad hoc queries, but should not be used in production.